# PHP - Best way to query database or collection by date and do sub calculations

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date

I have a collection/db of around 4k elements and each have a datetime and value e.g :

```
DATE                Value

2017-01-01 17:00    994.44
2017-01-01 18:00    998.56
2017-01-01 19:00    1231
2017-01-01 20:00    63546
2017-01-01 21:00    64534
2017-01-01 22:00    768
2017-01-01 23:00    74575
2017-01-02 0:00     76574
2017-01-02 1:00     345634
2017-01-02 2:00     7567
2017-01-02 3:00     8534
2017-01-02 4:00     1010.62
2017-01-02 5:00     647445
```

I want to get the time for each day that had the lowest value e.g for 2017-01-02 , i should get 2

Basically an array :

```
2017-01-02 => 2
2017-01-03 => 5
...
```

I'm not sure about the best way to query and run these sub calculations .

One way i was considering would be to query the table for each specific date i.e : "2017-01-02" and then calculate .

However i think that would be overkill in this case and also i don't know about the specific dates .

right now , i'm getting the entire table into a collection (using Laravel) :

```
$data = TableX::all();
```

Comment: Your input and output intersect only on 1 value, which is a completely arbitrary result that does not fit your description in absolutely any way.

Comment: On a side note: when will people stop using this lousy MySQL that doesn't treat nulls right, has no window functions (really needed in this scenario), no CTEs, no nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$data = TableX::select(
        DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(date, "%Y-%m-%d") AS date_formatted'), 
        DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(date, "%H-%i") AS time_formatted'), 
        DB::raw('MIN(value) AS min_value')
    )
     ->groupBy('date_formatted')
     ->get();
```

To access the result:

```
if (count($data) > 0) {

    foreach ($data as $row) {
        var_dump($row->date_formatted);
        var_dump($row->time_formatted);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks - it's somewhat working , however the time always returns 00-00

Comment: Change `%H-%i` to whatever you need. `%H:%i` gives you `00:00`. `%H` gives you the hour and `%i` the minutes.

Comment: i actually tried both . I think its not possible to to 2 date format in a raw query . I tried different things , even returning %T but still gives me 00:00:00

Comment: Nah, there were typos in the aliases (the double **t** was missing). Check the updated query.